# Text doesnt' appear after rerender

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

On the code below i run component will receive props to make sure that i pass it in the employee state. After i make sure that the employee is not null anymore, i want to display its info but it doesnt show up. I console.logged "did it" to see if it will log when the employee is fully loaded and passed in the state and the log appeared just fine. So why doesn't my text appear when the console.log actually is ran?(The data is fetched from firebase that's why i use component will receive props)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, LayoutAnimation, NativeModules, View, } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { onPress } from '../actions/index';
const { UIManager } = NativeModules

UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && 
UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true)

class FlatListItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show:false,
    employee:null
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.setState({employee:nextProps.employee})
  }

  renderDescription() {
    if (this.state.show)
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>Merge</Text>
        </View>
      )
  }

  renderHour () {
    let hour=this.props.class.hour;
    let minutes='';

    if (this.props.class.minutes < 10) { 
      minutes = `0${this.props.class.minutes}`;
    } else {
      minutes = this.props.class.minutes;
    }

    return (
      <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
        {hour}:{minutes}-{this.props.class.employeeUid}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  render() {
    LayoutAnimation.spring()
    console.log(this.state.employee);

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
        onPress={()=>{this.setState({show:!this.state.show})}}
      >
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            { console.log('rendered!!!!!') }
            { this.state.employee !==null ? <Text>123</Text> : null }
          </CardSection>
          { this.renderDescription() }
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = {
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15,
  }
}

export default FlatListItem;
```

The way I pass props to FLatListItem:

```
<ListView
                    enableEmptySections
                    dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(classi) => {
                        if (this.state.employees) {
                            const date = new Date();
                            const year = date.getFullYear();
                            const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                            const day = date.getDate();
                            let wantedEmployee = null;
                            if (this.state.employees !== null) {
                                this.state.employees.forEach(employee => {
                                    if (employee.uid === classi.employeeUid)
                                        wantedEmployee = employee;
                                });
                                if (classi.year === year && classi.month === month && day === classi.day)
                                    return <FlatListItem class={classi} employee={wantedEmployee} />;
                                else
                                    return null;
                            }
                            else
                                return null;
                        }
                    }

                    }
```

this.state.employees is set from a fetch from firebase so that is the reason that i am verifying id the state is null. The console.logs from FlatItemList if i enter console.log('did it!!') instead of 123 are:

```
23:22:35: null
23:22:35: rendered!!!!!
23:22:35: Object {
23:22:35:   "cnp": "3",
23:22:35:   "name": "3",
23:22:35:   "phone": "3",
23:22:35:   "registru": "3",
23:22:35:   "serie": "3",
23:22:35:   "shift": "Luni",
23:22:35:   "uid": "-LLugVdZk3wJ1LbgDuEU",
23:22:35: }
23:22:35: rendered!!!!!
23:22:35: did it!!
```

so you can clearly see that the if(this.state.employees!==null) from

```
<ListView
                enableEmptySections
                dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
                renderRow={(classi) => {
                    if (this.state.employees) {
                        const date = new Date();
                        const year = date.getFullYear();
                        const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                        const day = date.getDate();
                        let wantedEmployee = null;
                        if (this.state.employees !== null) {
                            this.state.employees.forEach(employee => {
                                if (employee.uid === classi.employeeUid)
                                    wantedEmployee = employee;
                            });
                            if (classi.year === year && classi.month === month && day === classi.day)
                                return <FlatListItem class={classi} employee={wantedEmployee} />;
                            else
                                return null;
                        }
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
                }

                }
```

is not working at all. Any ideeas?

Comment: what's the value of `nextProps` inside `componentWillReceiveProps`? How do you pass props to `FlatListItem`? Please, update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

That’s because render function triggers before componentWillReceiveProps, so console.log is null when it get call since state is not updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have compelling reason that you use `componentWillReceiveProps`?

If not, I think componentDidMount should work with this case.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // receive wantedEmployee from parent component set default value to be null if employee prop wasn't passed from parent component
  const {employee = null} = this.props;       

  // update employee state with employee from this.props
  this.setState({ employee }) // same as {employee: employee}
}
```

Also, this component will re-render its children with updated state if the state in ListView changed. If there is any reason that you intend to use `componentWillReceiveProps` specifically, please let me know with comment.

Comment: It didn't work. Now the employee is not even passed to the state anymore :(

Comment: Why do you want to have `employee` state in `FlatListItem ` component? I think you don't update that state with handler functions inside `FlatListItem` and that state handled by the parent component, so you can just pass `this.props.employee` to ` { this.state.employee !==null ? <Text>123</Text> : null }` instead of `this.state.employee`. `this.props.employee ? <Text>123</Text> : null`

Comment: i tried using state because i have already tried your suggestion. I tried it again and it still doesn't show up